# How many possible states?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

I have a vector with three items, where each item can adopt two different values.

```
1:  (a, b, c):

a = [1, 2]
b = [4, 8]
c = [500, 1000]
```

This throws a total of 8 possible different vectors. On the other side, I have another vector with 4 items that are initialized:

```
2: (32, 32, 10000, 10000)
```

Let's say every timestep, randomly a new vector 1 is created and changes vector 2 creating a state. The combination of vector 1 and 2 is a state. Vector 1 will affect vector 2 in the following way:

```
Ex. 

1 - (1, 4, 1000) then (28, 32, 9000, 10000)
2 - (2, 8, 500) then (28, 24, 9000, 9500)
3 - (1, 4, 500) then (24, 24, 8500, 9000)
```

Basically, item positions (1, 3) and (2, 4) of vector 2 are affected either by items in positions 2 and 3 of vector 1 respectively. Item position 1 in vector 1 determines which pair of items positions in vector 2 is going to be affected.

So in the previous example we have three possible states if we change the order in which vector 1 appears:

```
1 - (2, 8, 500) then (32, 24, 10000, 9500)
2 - (1, 4, 500) then (28, 24, 9500, 9500)
3 - (1, 4, 1000) then (20, 24, 8500, 9500)
```

Three new possible states.

```
1 - (1, 8, 1000) then (24, 32, 9000, 10000)
2 - (1, 8, 1000) then (16, 32, 8000, 10000)
3 - (2, 8, 1000) then (16, 24, 8000, 90000)
```

Again, different possible states.

My question is how to calculate all possible states that vector 1 and 2 can produce by the time, any of the items in position 1 and 2 of vector 2 reach 0.

A state is the combination of both vectors, that is to say:

```
State1 - (1, 8, 1000), (24, 32, 9000, 10000)
State2 - (1, 8, 1000), (16, 32, 8000, 10000)
State3 - (2, 8, 1000), (16, 24, 8000, 90000)
 ...
```

Comment: All possible states of the second vector after one first vector? After three first vectors? After any number?

Comment: I edited the question, to clarify it.

Comment: The question would not fundamentally change if you used $b'=[1,2]$ and $c'=[1,2]$ and started the second vector at $(8,8,20,20)$ but the arithmetic might be easier.  It then becomes obvious that the process will stop when one of the $8$s becomes $0$ or $-1$

Comment: I don't quite follow you.

Comment: Do you only care about these specific numbers, or do you need a general answer that works when $b$ and $c$ have different numbers?

Comment: Any way, if used for the specific numbers, the general maths can be extracted. At the end of the day the specific numbers don't matter, I think it matters more the number of possible vectors 1 (these will be determined by the possible different values that each vector item can have) that can exists and the number of possible vector 2 as a result of applying vector 1 on each step can conform each possible state.